# Why is my CoreML model out of scope in this, and how do I fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scope, coreml

[Screenshot of my Xcode and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbwgV.png)

I want to use the model like how Apple (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/integrating_a_core_ml_model_into_your_app)  describes in its CoreML documentation, where they state this:

`let model = MarsHabitatPicker()`

I tried to follow the Apple documentation, but I don't think I understood it, and do not know what to do to resolve this error. I also do not know how to adjust the settings of the model if necessary.

Comment: Make sure the model has a target selected and if it does deselect and then select again

Comment: Please provide some code, it's easier when it is in the post directly instead of an image